# How to share files among Xcode Projects

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made some categories of some classes such as NSArray and NSDictionary. I would like to use these categories in several projects. I may modify the files in any project, and I want all other projects get the updated files.

What's the best way to share files among projects?

I have read this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2126391/2880627) and this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311672/2880627). Someone recommended to add targets into the same project. This is not a good solution in my situation, because my projects are not related to each other, and I have many projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can create a static library and put all of your classes, class methods or sub classes then you can link to your individual projects.

> Static libraries provide a convenient mechanism for sharing code among
>   multiple applications. On iOS, static libraries are the only supported
>   library type. [This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH1-SW1) explains how to extract code from your
>   application into a new static library and how to use that static
>   library in multiple applications.

Whenever you want to add/edit/remove something you can edit and rebuild your library. [Creating the Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html) and [Creating a Static Library in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial).

When Xcode 6 and IOS 8 released IOS will support frameworks as well.